# fgets splits input string when I dont want it to

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, fgets

I'm using fgets to read in a line from a file, but it splits up the input line into multiple lines which is not what I want it to do.

This is the code that I'm using:

```
    char string[LMAX];
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("input.txt","r");


while(fgets (string, LMAX, fp) != NULL) {    //Reading the file, line by line
    printf("%s", string);  
}
```

For example if my input file had `1,2;0,5;7,8;0,6;;` the output in the console splits it up at the 0's.

i.e 
`1,2;
0,5;7,8;
0,6;;`

I want it to print in one single line

EDIT: Indeed it was an issue with my input file.

tldr: never use notepad

Comment: Are you on Windows? How did you create the input file?

Comment: yes, using VS2013 dev cmd to compile/run. I just opened up notepad and created the input file manually

Comment: and what is LMAX defined as?

Comment: works perfectly on Dev C++...? Maybe it's a visual studio thing

Comment: Notepad is not a programmer's tool. Never trust what you see in Notepad. Use a proper text editor.

Comment: suggest examining the contents of the file, to assure the 0s are actually 0x30 and not '\0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    int LMAX = 1024;
    char foo[LMAX];
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("input.txt","r");
    while(fgets (foo, LMAX, fp) != NULL) {    
    //Reading the file, line by line
        printf("%s", foo);
    }
}
```

Everything works fine on my system (though I'm running osx).

```
1,2;0,5;7,8;0,6;;
```

Coding wise, your logic and modifiers are sound. I expect the error in output is due to something inherent within Visual studios. Or there may be an issue with your input file.

Answer (score 0):

Try fgetc() or use fread() to read one byte at a time